# Puppet manifest isn't working. The error message is inexplicable and unhelpful

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, agent

I'm trying to compile (into a catalog) a manifest to be ran on a specific puppet agent node.  I am using Puppet 3.4 on the puppet master and agent servers.  I am using Ubuntu on AWS.  Here is the command that I am running on puppet master:  `puppet apply june1.pp`

Here is the output:

```
Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'puppet.us-west-1.compute.internal, puppet.us-west-1.compute, puppet.us-west-1, puppet' on node puppet.us-west-1.compute.internal
Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'puppet.us-west-1.compute.internal, puppet.us-west-1.compute, puppet.us-west-1, puppet' on node puppet.us-west-1.compute.internal
```

The output is unexpected.  The FQDN in the output above is for the puppet master server.  The manifest june1.pp is configured for the puppet agent server exclusively (except for a source file).  The source of the file to be copied in the manifest refers to the puppet master server.  I have tried taking out the reference to the puppet master server itself (which would make the manifest defective) and see what message the puppet apply command produces.  Sure enough I receive the same output.  I don't see why the manifest is producing output related to the puppet master server when the manifest doesn't mention the puppet master server itself.

What should I do to compile the manifest into the catalog for the puppet agent to eventually get the desired state configuration changes in my manifest named june1.pp?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `puppet apply filename.pp` in your master, you need to declare the puppet master as node or declare `default node`.

as you can see in your output the problem is very clear, for declare the default node you need something as follow.

/etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/default.pp

```
node default {
        include sshcon, motdclass, virtualhost
}
```

you don't need to include something.