# Puppet agent apply default configuration but doesn't apply node configuration

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

Puppet master version: 3.3.1

Puppet agent version: 3.3.1

Content of site.pp

```
import '*/*.pp'
node default {
include 'auth'
}
```

In the folder where site.pp is located there is folder called 'VirtualMachines' In 'VirtualMachines' folder there is file called: server1mycompanycom.pp

permissions for file server1mycompanycom.pp

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 puppet  sudo      81 Oct 15 14:33 server1_mycompany_com.pp
```

Content of file server1mycompanycom.pp

```
node 'server1.mycompany.com' inherits 'default' {
include 'zabbix::agent'
}
```

The problem is that when running

puppet agent --test

on server1.mycompany.com only module from default configuration is applied, which is called auth. Module from node configuration, which is called zabbix-agent is not applied.

Is anything wrong with site.pp? Other nodes works ok and apply configuration both from default section and from nodes section.

Comment: What's the output of `puppet agent --configprint certname` on the agent machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found the cause of the problem.

After adding new node you need to restart puppet master and after it puppet master start to apply node configuration.

How to restart puppet master:

By default, running the puppet master command will start a Puppet master server daemonized in the background. To stop the service, you’ll need to check the process table with something like ps aux | grep puppet, then kill the process.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/700872/puppet-manifest-isnt-working-the-error-message-is-inexplicable-and-unhelpful/700885#700885